# Define function for property of javascript class

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have this Javascript class and want to add some kind of function (like prototype)
to properties of this class.

```
function theUploader(virtualField)
{
     var self = this;
   //self.v = virtualField;
     self.v = (function(){return self.v; this.clear = function(){self.v = '';}})()
     self.v.prototype = function clear() {
       self.v = '';
     }
}
```

i tried those lines.
i couldn`t find out the right way to define such a thing.i want to call it like this

```
var temp = new theUploader('smart');
temp.v.clear();
```

someone guid me with jsaon.but still working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem(s) with this line:

```
self.v = (function(){return self.v; this.clear = function(){self.v = '';}})()
```

...would be more obvious if you split it out over several lines:

```
self.v = (function(){
             return self.v;
             this.clear = function(){
                             self.v = '';
             }
         })()
```

It's an immediately invoked function expression which returns on its first line, so it never gets to the `this.clear = ...` line. The value returned, `self.v`, will be `undefined` at that point, which means the `self.v` property you assign that value to will also be `undefined`, which means then on this line:

```
self.v.prototype = function clear() {
```

...you'll get an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'prototype' of undefined`.

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do given the confusion in your `theUploader()` function, but given that you said you want to be able to do this:

```
var temp = new theUploader('smart');
temp.v.clear();
```

Then you need to create a `.v` property that is itself an object that has a `.clear()` method, so:

```
function theUploader(virtualField)
{
     var self = this;
     self.v = {};                                // create a v property that is an object
     self.v.clear = function(){self.v = '';};    // add a method to v
}
```

...would do it. Or you could define the `clear` function directly in the object literal:

```
     self.v = {
        clear : function(){self.v = '';}
     };
```

(Either way it doesn't really make sense to me that calling `self.v.clear()` would actually overwrite the `.v` property with an empty string, but if that's what you want this is how you could do it.)

Comment: Thnanks.that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.v.prototype = function clear() {
   self.v = '';
}
```

Should be

```
self.v.clear = function() {
    self.v = '';
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that`s not worked.i tried that before.forget to mention that one